# React render component multiple times in container with different props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a reusable "tag" React component, so that users can create tags onclick and see that information displayed in the DOM.

Here's the module:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="language chip" data-lang={this.props.language} data-lang-level={this.props.level}>
        {this.props.language} ({this.props.level})
        <i className="material-icons">close</i>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And the onclick call:

```
var addLanguage = $('a#add-language');
addLanguage.click(function() {
  var languageLearning = $('#language-learning');
  var levelLearning =  $('#language-level');

  if (languageLearning != null && levelLearning != null) {

    ReactDOM.render(
      <LanguageChip
        language={languageLearning.val()}
        level={levelLearning.val()}
      />,
      document.getElementById('language-chips')
    );

    languageLearning.select2('val', '');
    levelLearning.select2('val', '');

  }
})
```

I didn't realise that when using React.DOM, "Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called." This means when adding a second chip, the first is removed. I want users to be able to have multiple chips.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've got a good reason to not add the form used to create a tag on your component, but it would be much simpler if you could.
Then you just have to add your tags on an array and display them with your `LanguageChip` component.

I've made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/snahedis/69z2wepo/28193/

I don't know what's your level of understanding of React so if something isn't clear let me know :)

**Edit:** the same example inside a preexistent form:
https://jsfiddle.net/snahedis/69z2wepo/28217/

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I don't want to do it via a form though, because the area I'm using this is actually already inside a form, so I'm getting nested form problems. Any advice to do this outside of a form?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You just have to use the click event of the button instead of the submit event of the form.
But if it's inside a form I guess you'll want to submit the tags with the form no ?

Comment: Yes, I need to submit the tags, but via JSON with a very particular structure so don't worry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use array to store multiple chips data. Take a look to this simplified example: http://output.jsbin.com/seficu

```
var LanguageChips = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {    
          (this.props.chipsArray).map(function(chip, index) {
            return <LanguageChip
              key={index}
              language={chip.languageLearning}
              level={chip.levelLearning}
            />
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var LanguageChip = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="language chip" data-lang={this.props.language} data-lang-level={this.props.level}>
        {this.props.language} ({this.props.level})
        <i className="material-icons"></i>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var chipsArray = [];

document.getElementById('add-language').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var languageLearning = 'test1';
  var levelLearning = 'test2';
  if (languageLearning != null && levelLearning != null) {
    chipsArray.push({
      languageLearning: languageLearning,
      levelLearning: levelLearning
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <LanguageChips chipsArray={chipsArray} />,
      document.getElementById('language-chips')
    );
  }
})
```